# Vue style tag not getting applied

Tags: vue.js

im trying to build a markdown blog website but I've ran into a bug. I use tailwindCSS for my project so all of the default styles are removed. So when I added markdown to my project it didn't look good as it shouldn't. However when I revert all styles like:

```
<style>
p{
    all: revert;
}
h1{
    all:revert;
}
h2{
    all:revert;
}
h3{
    all:revert;
}
```

... and so on.
It works perfectly while I'm in this *developing session*. However if I reload the page it doesn't work anymore. Feels like the style tag doesn't get applied but if I remove the style tag, save and paste it back in it works again.
It just feels like a weird bug does anyone know how to fix it? much appreciated

Comment: where are u declaring <style> tag ? is it in `App.vue` file?

Comment: In the component where im displaying the markdown, I just added it to app.vue but same thing happens, works till I reload page

Comment: to rewrite global styles u should use App.vue file

Comment: i have but didnt work

Comment: have you tried to add `<style scoped>` ?

Comment: yes also tried that with no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right i fixed it, if anyone has this bug. To revert certain elements back to their default styles. add the `all: revert` within the selector like I did but except of putting it in a vue component add it into the `index.css` where you import your tailwind